# iOS native QRCode scanner in Chinese Encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, utf-8, qr-code

This QRCode creates by Chinese Big5 Encoding not UTF-8, I am using iOS native class, AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject, try to get the result, but the string unreadable, like following:

**·s¦¡Àô«O­I:1:2:¯Â³ð¯ùºñ¯ù:2:20:¨Å­»¥@®a¥þ:1:83:­ìµÑ¤é¦¡ºñ:2:25:¥Í¬¡ªwªjºñ:2:10

I tried to convert the string to NSData by UTF-8, then I convert again from NSData to NSString, by others Encoding, and I thnik the original string already get wrong encoding  that is why I can convert to the correct string.

This is correct content:

**新式環保背:1:2:純喫茶綠茶:2:20:乳香世家全:1:83:原萃日式綠:2:25:生活泡沫綠:2:10

[image: The QRCode is here]

Does any way to get correct result using iOS native class? thanks

Comment: so what happened after you decode the string ?

Comment: did you get the correct string after you do the decoding ?

Comment: do you know how the data is encoded? I just created a QR code with chinese text and I got the same chinese characters after I scan it.

Comment: If you create QRCode by UTF-8 (most of QRCode generator by UTF8), It can get the correct result. But this QRCode is encoded by Big5 (this QRCode generator using Big5).

Comment: so you want to decode the Big5 data ?

Comment: This QRCode is from an invoice in my country, it has three different types, UTF8, Unicode, and Big5. But iOS native class only working on UTF8 and Unicode so far. But I need to find a way to scan all three types of format, and get correctly result.

Comment: How are you converting the "string to NSData by UTF-8"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the answer,
That QRCode contents string encoding is useing NSISOLatin1StringEncoding, not NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Code:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

    NSMutableString *message = [NSMutableString string];
    for (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *codeObject in metadataObjects) {

        NSInteger index = [metadataObjects indexOfObject:codeObject];

        NSString *readedString = codeObject.stringValue;

        // Restore raw data using NSISOLatin1StringEncoding.
        NSData *dataString = [readedString dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

        // Create big5 encoding.
        NSStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingBig5_HKSCS_1999);

        // Decode data using big5 encoding.
        readedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataString encoding:encoding];

        [message appendFormat:@"%zd. \"%@\"\n\n", index, readedString];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", message);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason is the QR code's encode is not correct.

i try to scan the code you show ,get the same result.
but i use the conent you provided, in this website(https://cli.im),recreate a new qrcode, then i scan it and get the correct result.